# How to find the reason why some errors occur when booting android devices

Tags: android, logging, boot, android-make

i have downloaded and built the android sources, and i have flashed some img files(system.img,boot.img,userdata.img,recovery.img,cache.img) into the android device.Then,i tried to start up the android device,but it was not successful to finish switching the android device on.The screen of the android device has been stuck in the boot screen.
are there some ways(such as the boot log) which can help me find the reason?

Answer (score 1):

1、you can catch the boot log by cmd,`adb logcat > abc.txt` when device booting
2、make sure your android source is suit for your device,ASOP source not an android ROM,need some drivers,kernel etc.

Comment: 首先adb命令没法连接设备；其次device目录和kernel目录我都有纳入设备自身厂商的固件。First,the adb command show "no device";Then,i copy some firmwares of the android device to the asop(such as the device dir and kernel).

Comment: See here  http://blog.csdn.net/fanmengke_im/article/details/22163339?utm_source=tuicool  ，catch the log , maybe the boot program has some wrong ,OMG,I can't use Chinese here.Are you Sure It hasn't some wrong when you compile the source.

Comment: building the source is success; i am sucessful to get the boot.img,system.img,recover.img.